# Determining the cause of org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe with Spring Boot 1.5 and Angular 5

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

So I have an API that receives GET request (Spring Boot), generates an excel file and returns it back to the client (Angular) and it works however I have been getting the following exception below while the front end receives a 504 response for files that are a bit larger and longer to generate.

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:342)
```

This is the java code that takes the excel workbook and returns it back out as a response:

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> doReturn(ResponseDTO responseDTO, String fileName, HttpServletRequest req,
        String methodName) throws Exception {

      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);

      Workbook workbook = responseDTO.getWorkbook();
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
          workbook.write(out);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          throw e;
      } finally {
        try {
            workbook.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.info("User: " + user + " failed to close exported file from " + methodName);
        }
      }

      ResponseEntity<?> resp = new ResponseEntity<>(out.toByteArray(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here is the Angular code that issues the request:

```
exportwithparam(url, fileName, Params): Observable<string> {
    let Headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(environment.roles.basicAuth)).set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return this.http
    .get(url, { headers: Headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer', observe: 'response', withCredentials: true, params: Params })
    .pipe(
        map(res => {
            let errmsg = "You have successfully exported " + fileName;
            if (res.ok) {
            let blob = new Blob([res.body], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            } else {
                let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                let a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = objectUrl;
                a.target = '_blank';
                a.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        }
        return errmsg;
  }),
  catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse): string => {
    if (err.status == 504) {
      throw "Gateway Time-out";
    } else {
      let errormessage = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(err.error));
      throw errormessage;
    }
  })
  )
}
```

I was wondering if there is anything I am doing wrong in the Java code that would cause this exception. However, if it is client that is dropping the connection then is there anything in Angular I can do ? I have tried setting a break point in VS Code just after the this.http.get and it seems for cases where the problem happens, it doesn't flow to the next line of code and directly goes to the catchError part at the bottom.

Also I need to note that this problem does not happen when I try this with both Spring Boot and Angular running in localhost. It happens when I either test this with Spring Boot running in our dev/test/prod environments. I know some of you may say the environment setting is the culprit but I just want to see if you guys notice anything before I draw that conclusion.

I have also tried just issuing the GET request as an URL with query params for these requests that would take longer to return a response and it also returns a 504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT.

Comment: Did you ever find the resolution?